# How to replicate Stata "factor" command in R

Tags: r, stata, factor-analysis

I'm trying to replicate some Stata results in R and am having a lot of trouble.  Specifically, I want to recover the same eigenvalues as Stata does in exploratory factor analysis.  To provide a specific example, the `factor` help in Stata uses `bg2` data (something about physician costs) and gives you the following results:

```
    webuse bg2
    factor bg2cost1-bg2cost6

(obs=568)

Factor analysis/correlation                        Number of obs    =      568
Method: principal factors                      Retained factors =        3
Rotation: (unrotated)                          Number of params =       15

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Factor  |   Eigenvalue   Difference        Proportion   Cumulative
-------------+------------------------------------------------------------
    Factor1  |      0.85389      0.31282            1.0310       1.0310
    Factor2  |      0.54107      0.51786            0.6533       1.6844
    Factor3  |      0.02321      0.17288            0.0280       1.7124
    Factor4  |     -0.14967      0.03951           -0.1807       1.5317
    Factor5  |     -0.18918      0.06197           -0.2284       1.3033
    Factor6  |     -0.25115            .           -0.3033       1.0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test: independent vs. saturated:  chi2(15) =  269.07 Prob>chi2 = 0.0000
```

I'm interested in the eigenvalues in the first column of the table.  When I use the same data in R, I get the following results:

```
   bg2 = read.dta("bg2.dta")
   eigen(cor(bg2)

   $values
   [1] 1.7110112 1.4036760 1.0600963 0.8609456 0.7164879 0.6642889 0.5834942
```

As you can see, these values are quite different from Stata's results.  It is likely that the two programs are using different means of calculating the eigenvalues, but I've tried a wide variety of different methods of extracting the eigenvalues, including most (if not all) of the options in R commands `fa`, `factanal`, `principal`, and maybe some other R commands.  I simply cannot extract the same eigenvalues as Stata.  I've also read through Stata's manual to try and figure out exactly what method Stata uses, but couldn't figure it out with enough specificity.

I'd love any help!  Please let me know if you need any additional information to answer the question.

Comment: It will be easier for people to help you if you post a small subsample of your data for people to play with in `R` and also post the factor analysis output from Stata for that subsample. To post a subsample just paste in the output from `dput`. For example, `dput(bg2[sample(1:nrow(bg2),20),])` will provide 20 randomly selected rows of data.

Comment: For now, maybe some of the options discussed here will help: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html.

Comment: You should be aware that the Note section in `?factanal` directly puts forth the notion that trying to compare factor analysis output across different implementations (let alone different languages altogether) is probably just hopeless. I've seen this asked several times, have never seen a conclusive answer, and so I'm of the opinion that it's just not worth even trying.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against carrying out a factor analysis on all the variables in the `bg2` data as one of the variables is `clinid`, which is an arbitrary identifier 1..568 and carries no information, except by accident.

Sensibly or not, you are **not** using the same data, as you worked on the 6 cost variables in Stata and those PLUS the identifier in R.

Another way to notice that would be to spot that you got 6 eigenvalues in one case and 7 in the other.

Nevertheless the important principle is that `eigen(cor(bg2))` is just going to give you the eigenvalues from a principal component analysis based on the correlation matrix. So you can verify that `pca` in Stata would match what you report from R.

So far, so clear.

But your larger question remains. I don't know how to mimic Stata's (default) factor analysis in R. You may need a factor analysis expert, if any hang around here.

In short, PCA is not equal to principal axis method factor analysis.

Different methods of calculating eigenvalues are not the issue here. I'd bet that given the same matrix Stata and R match up well in reporting eigenvalues. The point is that different techniques mean different eigenvalues in principle.

P.S. I am not an R person, but I think what you call R commands are strictly R functions. In turn I am open to correction on that small point.